# Ruby - Delete rows in csv file using enumerator CSV.open

Tags: ruby, csv

I know how to do it with CSV.read, but CSV.open and enumerator I'm not sure how. Or how do I omit those specific row before loading them in the new_csv[]  ?

Thanks!

```
new_csv = []
CSV.open(file, headers:true) do |unit|
     units = unit.each
     units.select do |row|
     #delete row [0][1][2][3]
     new_csv << row
end
```

[Code Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gxjtc.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to skip the first four rows plus the header, this are some options.

Get pure array:

```
new_csv = CSV.read(filename)[5..]
```

or keep the csv object

```
new_csv = []
CSV.open(filename, headers:true) do |csv|
  csv.each_with_index do |row, i|
    new_csv << row if i > 3
  end
end
```

or using [Enumerable#each_with_object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object):

```
csv = CSV.open(filename, headers:true)
new_csv = csv.each_with_index.with_object([]) do |(row, i), ary|
  ary << row if i > 3
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's begin by creating a CSV file:

```
contents =<<~END
name,nickname,age
Robert,Bobbie,23
Wilma,Stretch,45
William,Billy-Bob,72
Henrietta,Mama,53
END
  
FName = 'x.csv'

File.write(FName, contents)
  #=> 91
```

---

We can use [CSV::foreach](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/IO.html#method-c-foreach) without a block to return an enumerator.

```
csv = CSV.foreach(FName, headers:true)
  #=> #<Enumerator: CSV:foreach("x.csv", "r", headers: true)>
```

The enumerator `csv` generates [CSV::ROW](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Row.html) objects:

```
obj = csv.next
  #=> #<CSV::Row "name":"Robert" "nickname":"Bobbie" "age":"23">
obj.class
  #=> CSV::Row
```

Before continuing let me [Enumerator#rewind](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-rewind) `csv` so that `csv.next` will once again generate its first element.

```
csv.rewind
```

Suppose we wish to skip the first two records. We can do that using [Enumerator#next](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-next):

```
2.times { csv.next }
```

Now continue generating elements with the enumerator, mapping them to an array of hashes:

```
loop.map { csv.next.to_h }
  #=> [{"name"=>"William", "nickname"=>"Billy-Bob", "age"=>"72"},
  #    {"name"=>"Henrietta", "nickname"=>"Mama", "age"=>"53"}]
```

See [Kernel#loop](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) and [CSV::Row#to_h](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Row.html#method-i-to_h). The enumerator `csv` raises a `StopInteration` exception when `next` invoked after the enumerator has generated its last element. As you see from its doc, `loop` handles that exception by breaking out of the loop.

`loop` is a very versatile method. I generally use it in place of `while` and `until`, as well as when I need it to handle a `StopIteration` exception.

---

If you just want the values, then:

```
csv.rewind
2.times { csv.next }
loop.with_object([]) { |_,arr| arr << csv.next.map(&:last) }
  #=> [["William", "Billy-Bob", "72"],
  #    ["Henrietta", "Mama", "53"]]
```